# Vertically centering an overflowing widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a bit of user generated content that is restricted to a specific height. Anything over that height should be overflowing and clipped off.

I've achieved that by wrapping the content with a Wrap widget, however the extra requirement i have is that the overflowed content should always be centered in its parent, see image below

[image]

The current behaviour is the first red box, but what I'm looking for is to vertically center the content similarly to box #2

Example code I've used is:

```
Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 40, maxHeight: 40),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      child: Wrap(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Text('Line1'),
              Text('Line2'),
              Text('Line3'),
              Text('Line4'),
              Text('Line5'),
              Text('Line6'),
              Text('Line8'),
              Text('Line9'),
              Text('Line10'),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

I've tried the various alignment properties the Wrap widget offers, however none of them did the trick. Is there a specific flutter widget I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `FittedBox` (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html) with `BoxFit.none` (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit.html#none) to center the child in the available space while clipping everything outside.

```
Container(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 40, maxHeight: 40),
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.red,
  ),
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
  child: FittedBox(
    fit: BoxFit.none,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text('Line4'),
        Text('Line5'),
        Text('Line6'),
        Text('Line8'),
        Text('Line9'),
        Text('Line10'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you